# SceneKit – Rotate SCNNode around its own top left point

Tags: swift, scenekit

How can I rotate a SCNNode around its own point left top.

It is possible to set an anchor or something else?

Comment: I assume you talk about the geometry pivot point hold by the node. You can shift the pivot by using a SCNMatrixMakeTranslation object.

Comment: Thank you, that's it. First set pivot, than rotate.